# /users/1 to /users/loginName

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permalinks

although this question sound noob.. but i really need to know this. What is in controller and routes to make the url like i want??

any reference?? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want to do is to redefine your to_params to return :name instead of :id.

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    name
  end
end

user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
user_path(user)  # => "/users/Phusion"
```

That should do it.

Comment: +1, but is it possible to overwrite the params variable name? I would prefer `User.find_by_name(params[:name])` to `User.find_by_name(params[:id])` in the controller.

Comment: hey man, i got this error "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" im on rails 3.. am i miss something???

Comment: @PeterWong, I don't understand what it is you're asking.  If you want to you User.find_by_name(params[:name]), there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: akk, where did you get this error?  Post your own question and I"ll answer it there.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your names need to be unique.
A nice gem to use is [friendly_id](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/), which will handle most cases very nicely, including transcription to ascii, handeling duplicates and so on.